# Unable to print dbms output

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to print the output for the below sql block when it says c1_list is not a cursor. Could anyone tell me what I could be missing.

```
  Declare
  Cursor c1 is 
  select store_id ,geometry from TMCS.TMCS_All_Stores_TA  where CLIENT_ID= 1 and rownum <1;

  Type C1_TAB_TYPE is table of c1%ROWTYPE;      
  c1_list c1_TAB_TYPE;

    --   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2012 Population--> '||c1_list(1).store_id); 

  Begin     
            For r1 in c1 
               Loop

               select  store_id ,geometry 
                BULK COLLECT INTO c1_list from
               (
                  select 
                  store_id, store_number ,geometry 
                  from TMCS.TMCS_ALL_STORES_TA
                  where client_id=1
                  and   SDO_RELATE(Geometry, r1.geometry,'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE'
                  and store_id != r1.store_id
               );


                     For r1 in c1_list
                     Loop
                     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2012 Population--> '||r1.store_id);  
                      End Loop;
            End Loop;

  End;
```

Comment: Do you have set serveroutput on as first statement? If this is not you are looking for Could you please explain your question in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c1_list is not a cursor, it is a variable. You can do it like this:

```
For i in c1_list.First..c1_list.Last loop
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2012 Population--> '||c1_list(i).store_id); 
end loop;
```